# Applying the activation function in this way is equivalent to the other way - RNN

Tags: time-series, natural-language, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I don't understand why in RNN the 2 following ways of applying the activation functions are equivalent:

First way:
$$
h_t = W\sigma(h_{t-1}) + U x_t + b
$$
Second way:
$$
g_t = \sigma(Wg_{t-1} + U x_t + b)
$$

I do understand that $g_t$ and $h_t$ are not the same but I do not understand what is the relationship between the 2 and how they are equivalent.

Could you please explain it to me or give me a resource that does it?

Comment: Wh told you these are equivalent? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: it was in our course, the prof said it but there is no resources and the prof is hard to contact